# The required anti-forgery cookie is not present when posting to webpage in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

There are a lot of questions here that seem to be from the web page building side, but it is a lot harder from the client prospective.  I am attempting to fill out (what I hope) is a simple login form and then use the cookie it returns to make web api calls because this web api requires a form login before a user can make calls.  Below is my code it is currently returning the error that the required anti-forgery cookie is not present.

```
 public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }

  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
            client.BaseAddress = @"https://telogapi.placeholder.org/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F";
            var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
            loginData.Add("login", "user");
            loginData.Add("password", "password");
            client.UploadValues("/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F", "POST", loginData);

            //Now you are logged in and can request pages    
            string htmlSource = client.DownloadString("index.php");
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            var pageContent = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream())
                                     .ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of `var client` after `var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();` ?  More specifically, do properties get the expected values when you debug and step through `GetWebRequest` ?

Comment: content length is -1 so I'm going to go with it is null right after that line is executed.  I put all of the code, literally all of it here, with only censoring the site and credentials, so I havn't really done anything to populate it beyond whatever comes as default.  As to expected values, I don't know what to really look for.  The code failes onthe return request step from GetWebRequest